# Minimize Rich Text editor encoded content in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have a custom field of type `Rich Text` in inventory page. I uploaded 1 files to the editor and a table. While fetching the data with below code:

```
itemRecord.getValue({ fieldId: "custitem_productspecifications" });
```

The data of Rich Text is too long because the file URL is saved in base64 encoded.

The sample output data is like below:

```
<figure class=\\"image\\"><img src=\\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...........extremely long text>
```

Is there any way I can get the content in shorter?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily shorten your example by changing the `src` attribute to an `http(s)` URI rather than a data URI. This would mean the data for the image would be stored elsewhere (possibly in the NetSuite file cabinet) and only linked to from the rich text field.

However, it may be even better to remove the image from the rich text field altogether and store it in a separate "image" type custom field.